# How to convert a decimal integer to bytes with php?

Tags: php, math, int, decimal, byte

I need to get how much bytes is a decimal integer with php.
For example how can I know if 256,379 is 3-bytes with php?
I need a php function to pass 256,379 as input and get 3 as output. How can I have it?

Comment: The `PHP_INT_SIZE` constant tells you how large an integer value will be in PHP.... but I can't understand where you get a possible value of 3 from.... integers are either 4 or 8 bytes (32-bit or 64-bit), and will be consistent for your version of PHP.... they won't vary

Comment: I know that, and on 64-bits cpu, of course it is 8, but how can I know if a particular decimal value is how much bytes with php? for example how do I know if 25,637,959,676 is 5 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need calculate logarithm like this:

```
echo ceil( log ($nmber, 256) );
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of bytes needed to represent a number can be calculated like this:

```
echo getNumBytes(256379); // Output: 3
echo getNumBytes(25637959676); // Output 5

function getNumBytes($num) {
    $i = 1;
    do {
        $i++;
    } while(pow(256,$i) < $num);
    return $i;
}
```